# Passing integer values from servlet to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am getting values from user using a html file which is then used by the servlet to perform certain calculations.And when i execute my web application in the browser it takes values from user but when i click the submit button after getting values,this error is thrown.
"HTTP ERROR 500
Problem accessing /servlet/MvcServlet. Reason:
    java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String"

My servlet code is like this:

```
int gpa=total/c;
req.setAttribute("gpa",gpa);
RequestDispatcher view = req.getRequestDispatcher("/result.jsp");
view.forward(req, resp); `
```

and my jsp code is:

```
String gpa = (String) request.getAttribute("gpa");
int r=Integer.parseInt(gpa);
out.println("Your Result is "+ r);
```

Please help me out for passing my integer value "gpa" in servlet to jsp.

Comment: `int r = ((Integer)request.getAttribute("gpa")).intValue();`

Answer (score 2):

int gpa = (Integer) request.getAttribute("gpa");

Answer (score 2):

The obvious answer would be to obtain the data as `Integer` and let Java autounbox it to an `int`. This is notable by this piece of code:

```
int gpa = (Integer) request.getAttribute("gpa");
```

But you [**should avoid having scriptlets (Java code) directly in your code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197). So the best bet would be using Expression Language directly in your JSP code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <!-- head content here -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- other content in your JSP file -->
        Your result is: ${gpa}
        <!-- There's no need of senseless scriptlet code -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you send the int value to the jsp you can try this

```
int gpa = total/c;

String test = ""+gpa;
req.setAttribute("test",test);
RequestDispatcher view = req.getRequestDispatcher("/result.jsp");
    view.forward(req, resp);
```

And then in the jsp you dont have to parse it . Just directly go -

```
String gpa = (String) request.getAttribute("test");
out.println("Your Result is "+ gpa);
```

Try this :D

Comment: If the variable is already an `int`, there's no need to add overhead to convert it into a `String` to convert it back to `int`.